# How to refer to other resources and outputs in Terragrunt?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terragrunt

I was following this tutorial for multi-env deployment with Terragrunt in GCP: https://harjot.me/blog/deploying-docker-containers-to-gke-using-terraform/

As you can see he didn't finish the gcp-sql moudule example and now I don't know how do I refer to other resources or outputs that are in a different folders using this template.
For instance :

a module in `terraform>module>gcp-sql>main.tf`

needs a value from  `terraform>module>gcp-gke>main.tf` such as `module.gcp_services.project_id`

or

it needs a value from  `terraform>module>gcp-gke>outputs.tf` such as `module.gke.cluster_endpoint` (I'm not even sure this is the correct way to refer to the output, do I really need to specify module name "gke"?)

So in short,using this template from tutorial if a module that is using a value from another module but both modules are in the same main.tf such as `erraform>module>gcp-gke>main.tf`  file then yes I can use `module.gcp_services.project_id` but will the same apply if the second moudule is in a different main.tf file. If yes, how is it aware of the other module? And again, how do I use outputs?

Comment: Have you checked `dependencies` in Terragrunt? It's a way to get output from one module and use it as an input for another module. https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/execute-terraform-commands-on-multiple-modules-at-once/#passing-outputs-between-modules

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thanks.